# Question related to root directory for containerd, docker, kubeadm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, containerd

All.

I have questions about the purpose of root directory for containerd, docker, kubeadm.
I've been trying to change the root directory from default to specific directory.

As far as I known, there are 3 types of root directory like below.

- docker : --data-root /var/lib/docker
- containerd : --root /var/lib/containerd
- kubeadm : --root-dir /var/lib/kubeadm

Please anyone let me know exactly about what those directories are used for.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you try to change these directories ?

Answer (score 1):

These are the implementation specific paths for these runtimes. With docker all your containers, images and their related information is stored in /var/lib/docker,
same is the case for containerd.io which stores all its container related objects in /var/lib/containerd